# Scroll to top of a dialog using Angular Material Dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material

Using the [Angular Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) component to display two forms (one is hidden while another one is filled out). After the first form is submitted, it is hidden and the second one is displayed (in the same dialog).

The problem: when the first form is hidden and the second one is displayed, the scroll position is not updated (to show the top of the dialog) so the user sees the middle or bottom part of the second form.

I tried to do `window.scroll` or `scrollTo` functions but they did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Chan you show some code, specially how you are hiding/displaying your forms please ?

Comment: @QuentinGrisel Just using a boolean property inside a controller and doing  `*ngIf` check in the view.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

**Solution 1: Use `*ngIf` to hide your forms**

I think you best approach might be to use the *ngIf directive to hide elements instead of using the `[hidden]` attribute. The advantage of using `*ngIf` is that it will not render elements in the DOM if the condition is not met. Therefore it will not effect the scroll position if an element is hidden.

**Solution 2: Use `scrollIntoView()`**

You could use the `Element.scrollIntoView()` method to scroll the element into the view. First you need to get the element you want to display in the viewport which in this case would be second `<form></form>` element. Get the element by using `document.getElementbyId()` or use an Angular `ViewChild` and call the `scrollIntroView()` method on the element.
[MDN Web Docs - Element.scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)